# JNI : Unable to find java class from native method in a callback

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm fairly new with JNI and I'm struggling with this problem.

I have a c++ callback being called by a network library (alljoyn).

In this callback, I need to call Java code.

Since this callback is in another thread, I use the following code to get a JNIEnv pointer :

(jvm being a global pointer)

```
JNIEnv *env = NULL;  
jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
```

Problem is, when I try to call FindClass with this env pointer, the result is NULL.

If I do the exact same FindClass call within my main thread, everything works just fine.

How can I fix this ? Is this somehow related to the classpath ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FindClass from any thread in Android JNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263340/findclass-from-any-thread-in-android-jni)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer and the official workaround can be found on [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass). If you must go beyond pre-caching global references for all classes your native code might need, you will find a successful solution that caches the correct class loader here: [FindClass from any thread in Android JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263340/findclass-from-any-thread-in-android-jni)

Comment: I had to cache the jclass / jobj and the memthodID as well but it works. Still a ugly hack.