# How to enable/disable wifi in android device through native code(java) in qt c/c++?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I successfully managed `wifi` *enable* through java code with Android studio but not able to do same with qt c/c++..
 i have tried the java method.. it's working perfectly in android

```
public static  void enableWifi(Context context){
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);//Turn on Wifi
    }
```

calling from c/c++ :

```
QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("com/app/MyJavaClass",
                                                           "enableWifi",
                                                         "(Landroid/content/Context;)V",
                                                            QtAndroid::androidContext().object());
```

I wasn't able to enable `wifi` in Android device using c/c++.. how can i achieve this? please help me out...
 Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested with Android, and it does work, I could do both enable and disable `WiFi`, How and where you configured your java class in Qt?

Comment: I was tried to connect wifi when click on button in Qt..
This is the way i am calling method from c++
void calljava::wificonnection(){
 QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("com/app/sampleandroidproject/MyJavaClass",
                                                           "enableWifi",
                                                         "(Landroid/content/Context;)V",
                                                            QtAndroid::androidContext().object());
}

Comment: is any permissions required like android  for wifi in qt? please help me

Comment: Have  look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940444/where-does-qt-look-for-java-classes-when-using-jni/48950527#48950527) and make sure you doing it correctly. add permissions _ACESS_WIFI_STATE_, _CHANGE_WIFI_STATE_

Comment: I did the same way... I have added permissions in manifest file. But I wasn't able to enable wifi.

Comment: I just added manifest file under android source directory in Qt.. is manifest need to call anywhere ?

Comment: What do you mena by _call anywhere_ ?

Comment: I have added like this in my .pro file
DISTFILES += \
    android/src/MyJavaClass.java \
    android/src/AndroidManifest.xml

When i click on button, calling wifi related method.. i am getting log like this 
I/WifiManager( 4935): setWifiEnabled : true
But not able to connect wifi.. please  help me