# Android JNI: Possible reasons a Java class can be found by native code in earlier code turns into not able to be found later?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm new to android development especially developing with JNI.

Unfortunately(or fortunately?) I'm working on a project which has almost been completed.Most of its logic is written in native c++ code.

The problem is: while running the project, native code can't find Java class ClassJavaA, but when I put code to find this class in some code executed earlier, the class can be found.

Since it's quite hard to debug the chunky native c++ code, I'm wondering if there are some typical possible reasons causing this phenomenon.

Any clue is welcome, thanks.

PS:
Thread attaching is not the problem, I've checked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like this issue:

[FAQ: Why didn't FindClass find my class?](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass)

> If the class name looks right, you could be running into a class loader issue.

And the recommended workarounds are:

> - Do your FindClass lookups once, in JNI_OnLoad, and cache the class references for later use. Any FindClass calls made as part of executing JNI_OnLoad will use the class loader associated with the function that called System.loadLibrary (this is a special rule, provided to make library initialization more convenient). If your app code is loading the library, FindClass will use the correct class loader.
> - Pass an instance of the class into the functions that need it, by declaring your native method to take a Class argument and then passing Foo.class in.
> - Cache a reference to the ClassLoader object somewhere handy, and issue loadClass calls directly. This requires some effort.

There's an example of the last one here:

[FindClass from any thread in Android JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263340/findclass-from-any-thread-in-android-jni)