# Jni FindClass returns NULL

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I got c++ structs in header file,

```
struct StatusLine
{
    static jclass Class; // Lorg/apache/http/StatusLine;
    static jmethodID GetStatusCode; // ()I
};

struct ByteArrayOutputStream 
{
    static jclass Class; // Ljava/io/ByteArrayOutputStream;
    static jmethodID Constructor; // ()V
    static jmethodID Close; // ()V
    static jmethodID ToByteArray; // ()[B
};

struct HttpEntity
{
    static jclass Class; // Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;
    static jmethodID WriteTo; // (Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V
    static jmethodID GetContent; // ()Ljava/io/InputStream;
};
```

and cpp file is

```
 #define JAVA_STATUS_LINE_CLASS             "org/apache/http/StatusLine"
 #define JAVA_HTTP_ENTITY_CLASS             "org/apache/http/HttpEntity"
 #define JAVA_BYTE_ARRAY_OUTPUT_STREAM_CLASS "java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream"

 jclass StatusLine::Class = 0;
 jmethodID StatusLine::GetStatusCode = 0;

 jclass  ByteArrayOutputStream::Class = 0;
 jmethodID ByteArrayOutputStream::Constructor = 0;
 jmethodID ByteArrayOutputStream::Close = 0;
 jmethodID ByteArrayOutputStream::ToByteArray = 0;

 jclass HttpEntity::Class = 0;
 jmethodID HttpEntity::WriteTo = 0;
 jmethodID HttpEntity::GetContent = 0;

 void initializeJniPointers()
 {
      StatusLine::Class = GetJniEnv()->FindClass(JAVA_STATUS_LINE_CLASS);
      StatusLine::GetStatusCode = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(StatusLine::Class, "getStatusCode", "()I");


      ByteArrayOutputStream::Class = GetJniEnv()->FindClass(JAVA_BYTE_ARRAY_OUTPUT_STREAM_CLASS);
      ByteArrayOutputStream::Constructor = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(ByteArrayOutputStream::Class, "<init>", "()V");
      ByteArrayOutputStream::Close = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(ByteArrayOutputStream::Class, "close", "()V");
      ByteArrayOutputStream::ToByteArray = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(ByteArrayOutputStream::Class, "toByteArray", "()[B");

      HttpEntity::Class = GetJniEnv()->FindClass(JAVA_HTTP_ENTITY_CLASS);
      HttpEntity::WriteTo = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(HttpEntity::Class, "writeTo", "(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V");
      HttpEntity::GetContent = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(HttpEntity::Class, "getContent", "()Ljava/io/InputStream;");
 }
```

function initializeJniPointers() crushes on line StatusLine::GetStatusCode = GetJniEnv()->GetMethodID(); because StatusLine::Class is NULL. 
   But! I notice that:
If I write this in some java file of the project
     StatusLine l = new StatuLine()
     {
         ...
     }

Function crushes on ByteArrayOutputStream::Constructor because ByteArrayOutputStream::Class is NULL, if I create an object of ByteArrayOutputStream in java, function will go further to the next object, etc... I notice that: If I just declare a variable of ByteArrayOutputStream, findClass will return NULL.

Could someone explain me what to do? BTW I use Android 2.3.5 device Samsung GT-S5363, I tried other vertions of android (elder) and devices and it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically this can occur if the thread where you ask `FindClass` is not the main thread and in your thread system does not build a map of java class IDs.

Check this out, probably you have to ask `FindClass` first in the main thread (when JNI loads or somewhere else), and then you will have ability to do that in any thread.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/jni-findclass-cannot-find-a-class-if-its-called-by-a-new-pthread/1873/4

Also try this out, this worked for me:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mesos/branches/0.10.x/src/java/jni/convert.cpp

The solution (taken from link above) is finding a Java class loader from your app in `JNI_OnLoad` and ask him to find class then from any thread. Otherwise, after calling `env->FindClass` JNI can fall back to the system class loader which loads only system classes like `String`.

Comment: I guess so, because after i load classes manualy, pointers returned fine. But I got this problem only with Android 2.x version. On Android 4.x versions this bug didn't occures.

Comment: For me this problem occured only on Android > 5.0

Comment: Not tested this solution on < 4.0.4 though.

Comment: For a complete code solution to this, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16302771/1046167 and its comments.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique that has worked for me is to instantiate an object of the needed class, Java-side, just before the native method call (e.g. in AsyncTask doInBackground()).