# JNI call to find Java class from native results in NoCLassDefFoundError

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am using following code to access a java class from native code

```
JNIEnv *env = nullptr;

JMVEnv::attachCurrentJNIENv(&env);

jclass jXYZClass = env->FindClass("com/xxx/xx/xx/XYZClassName");
```

This call passes 4-5 times but fails after that. jXYZClass is null after some calls.

So, while compilation class is found and during execution also it was found 4-5 times. I am calling this code from different locations. Can it be some threading issue?

Comment: I think it is a threading problem...

Comment: This seems related: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass  In particular the last section regarding ClassLoaders.

Comment: Above post resolved the issue. I tool global ref to jclass instead of local ref. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a multhreading problems... Especially when you say that " **it was found 4-5 times. I am calling this code from different locations**".

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263340/findclass-from-any-thread-in-android-jni) for more details.

Firstly, you can print the thread id of each thread to see if they are the same thread.

You can Findclass in JNI_OnLoad:

```
jobject g_class;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *pjvm, void *reserved) {
    JavaVM *gJvm = pjvm;  // cache the JavaVM pointer
    JNIEnv *env= NULL;
    env = gJvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    jclass tmp = env->FindClass("com/xxx/xx/xx/XYZClassName");
    g_class = env->NewGlobalRef(tmp);
}
```

whenever you want to use this class:

```
// extern jobject g_class; Add this Line if this is in another cpp file
jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID((jclass)g_class, "<init>", "()V");
jobject new_object = env->NewObject((jclass)g_class, methodID);
```